# Register all GUI components as Observers or pass current object to next object as a constructor argument?

Tags: java, design-patterns

First, I'd like to say that I think this is a common issue and there may be a simple or common solution that I am unaware of. Many have probably encountered a similar problem. Thanks for reading.

I am creating a GUI where each component needs to communicate (or at least be updated) by 
multiple other components. Currently, I'm using a Singleton class to accomplish this goal. Each GUI component gets the instance of the singleton and registers itself. When updates need to be made, the singleton can call public methods in the registered class. I think this is similar to an Observer pattern, but the singleton has more control. Currently, the program is set up something like this:

```
class c1 {
    CommClass cc;
    c1() {
        cc = CommClass.getCommClass();
        cc.registerC1( this );
        C2 c2 = new c2();
    }
}

class c2 {
    CommClass cc;
    c2() {
        cc = CommClass.getCommClass();
        cc.registerC2( this );
        C3 c3 = new c3();
    }
}

class c3 {
    CommClass cc;
    c3() {
        cc = CommClass.getCommClass();
        cc.registerC3( this );
        C4 c4 = new c4();
    }
}
```

etc.

Unfortunately, the singleton class keeps growing larger as more communication is required between the components.

I was wondering if it's a good idea to instead of using this singleton, pass the higher order GUI components as arguments in the constructors of each GUI component:

```
class c1 {
    c1() {
        C2 c2 = new c2( this );
    }
}

class c2 {
    C1 c1;
    c2( C1 c1 ) {
        this.c1 = c1
        C3 c3 = new c3( c1, this );
    }
}

class c3 {
    C1 c1;
    C2 c2;
    c3( C1 c1, C2 c2 ) {
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        C4 c4 = new c4( c1, c2, this );
    }
}
```

etc.

The second version relies less on the CommClass, but it's still very messy as the private member variables increase in number and the constructors grow in length.

Each class contains GUI components that need to communicate through CommClass, but I can't think of a good way to do it.

If this seems strange or horribly inefficient, please describe some method of communication between classes that will continue to work as the project grows. Also, if this doesn't make any sense to anyone, I'll try to give actual code snippets in the future and think of a better way to ask the question. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the Observer pattern itself ? Each component can manintain a list of listeners to be updated, and it provides methods to register/unregsister listeners. Since you are already aware of Observer pattern any specific reason for using Singleton ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The Observer pattern you suggested is probably the way to go. The main problem I have with it, is that there are so many components to register that it keeps getting larger. I should probably mention that there are other things contained in the Singleton that I'm not sure where else to put, like global information about the user. One component may need the user's name, another may need the user's birth date or other information. This is all contained in it's own UserInfo class, but the Singleton is keeping up with which User is loaded at the time.

Comment: A major reason not to do the second one is that you're giving away a reference to "this" in the constructor - this can cause a number of Very Bad Things to happen.  (As an example, if you have a C1Subclass extends C1, then when you do new C2(this) in C1's constructor, none of C1Subclass's constructor has executed yet.)

Comment: Nice question, you should imho definitely read the GoF Design Patterns book, they work there with GUI realted examples. You can use observers combined with Composite pattern and maybe even Chain of Responsibility, it all depends on communication behaviours in your application.

Comment: You may also want to check out other UI-related patterns such as MVC, MVP or MVVM. Fowler has a pretty good description of GUI architectures at http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html. Maybe the simplest change improvement, though, would be to unify the control registration so that all the controls implement a common interface and register via a single addListener method.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to judge if what you are trying to do can be solved by using  [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). With the use of the [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) principle you can, if you have some well defined interfaces inject them into the constructors of objects without for you the need to do it explicitly. It is done using a framework like [String](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html), which makes use of a container and reflexion to perform the task.

There are many assumptions on the use case like:

- You can use interfaces to distinguish which objects register on others
- Not sure about this one: only one object for a given interface can be added to the container

I am not a specialist for Spring but the IoC I use has the "limitation". Usually IoC is used for services and not for GUI elements, so take this answer with a grain of salt. I hope it gives you a new helpful impulse towards a good solution for the scalability you are looking for. At least the IoC provides a very good decoupling between the objects.